# Is asking how to deal with animals/insects etc... on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Is dealing with animals/insects etc... on-topic on this stack exchange?
I'm talking about preventing or dealing with wasps, raccoons, etc... within your home region.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

We have [pest-control](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pest-control) and [pest](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pest) tags, both of which have quite a few questions.

However, please be careful. When it comes to questions about protected species (bats in the UK for example) we can't answer as that comes under legal advice.